# Redirect error in Google Webmaster Tools report

Tags: google-search-console

I built a CMS and I used it to create the following website http://www.tkdmontecatini.com . After some days, Google Webmaster Tools started to give me several "Redirect error" on some pages like the follows:

- http://www.tkdmontecatini.com/it/photogallery
- http://www.tkdmontecatini.com/it/pagina/9/Informazioni/Corsi/Chi-Siamo
- http://www.tkdmontecatini.com/it/pagina/2/Informazioni/Eventi/Eventi

The funny things are:

1. If I access those links from a browser, it's all right and I've not redirect loops or other similar issues
2. If I use the "Fetch as Googlebot" function, I get a great "Success" result

**Question**: Any idea of why this happens and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Google doesn't like pages in the sitemap that do redirect. Google don't want redirects at all also if this is done in the right way and using status code 301 or 302 (where necessary) with a good landing page. Thus, there're two possibilites to solve the problem:

1. Don't let the page in the sitemap to redirect (the pages must give status code 200)
2. Change the pages in the sitemap with the landing ones.

Answer (score 4):

To solve these kinds of issues, I suggest you use [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL). This is a command line tool in linux / unix and I suppose there are equivalents in other operating systems.

cURL lets you see what the server is returning in terms of headers or output without all the interference of a browser. In this case I use curl -I [url] which shows me just the headers that are returned.

I ran curl -I [url] on the links you provided and they are all returning 302 Temporary Redirect, redirecting the user to other URLs. This could be a problem with your apache configuration or with your CMS.

Here's the output.

```
greg@greg-desktop:~$ curl -I http://www.tkdmontecatini.com/it/photogallery
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Sun, 13 Nov 2011 07:21:37 GMT
Server: Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.6 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=4d70b639d7aabf8a2f42c57c595f7610; path=/
Location: /it/photogallery
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

greg@greg-desktop:~$ curl -I http://www.tkdmontecatini.com/it/pagina/9/Informazioni/Corsi/Chi-Siamo
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Sun, 13 Nov 2011 07:22:08 GMT
Server: Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.6 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=99325602d521a419e2cdf7ca279ca995; path=/
Location: /it/pagina/9/Informazioni/Corsi
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type: text/html

greg@greg-desktop:~$ curl -I http://www.tkdmontecatini.com/it/pagina/2/Informazioni/Eventi/Eventi
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Sun, 13 Nov 2011 07:22:36 GMT
Server: Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.6 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=aa177b2717c41d0b8deb8dc948a69df6; path=/
Location: /it/pagina/2/Informazioni/Eventi
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: +1 - You gave me the hint to find what was the problem and how to solve it.