# php fopen => 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, xampp, http-code-500

I have a website hosted on a dedicated server, I noticed that Google and other search engines can't access to the most URLs on my website!!

On my localhost I have made a small test :

```
var_dump(fopen('http://www.aswat.ma', 'r'));
```

And I got this error :

> Warning: fopen(http://www.aswat.ma) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in C:\xampp\htdocs\pnowate\public\index.php on line 4
>   bool(false)

If I change the URL "http://www.aswat.ma" by "www.google.co.ma" I got this :

> resource(3) of type (stream)

Any one have any idea about this issue ??

Answer (score 1):

To check this kind of issue, you can use a website like [www.hurl.it](http://www.hurl.it). Anyway I see you used Zend Framework to develop the website and I think you have the almost same problem I had (or at least you can solve the same way). Thus, take a look at my question and my answer. It works for me: [Redirect error in Google Webmaster Tools report](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21948/redirect-error-in-google-webmaster-tools-report)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Using your tool such as http://www.hurl.it I have found the error :) this error apears just when access to my website without a browser! Cause I'm trying to get Language from BROWSER like this : `$locale->setLocale(Zend_Locale::BROWSER);` Regards.